# Subtraction using 15s complement

Tags: arithmetic, number-formats

I know 15s complement subtraction may not be much taught/popular one, but I just want to give it a try. Just trying to clear my basic digital logic/number systems concepts.

Here is what I am doing:

**Normal decimal subtraction**

$(339)_{10}-(401)_{10}=(-62)_{10}$

**1's complement subtraction**

$(101010011)_2-(110010001)_2=(101010011)_2+(001101110)_{\text{1s comp}}=111000001$
No end over carry generated. That is the result is -ve and is in 1's complement form. Taking back 1's complement, we get $000111110$. Thus the solution is $(-000111110)_2$

This sounds correct as $(62)_{10}=(111110)_2$

However this is not working with 15's complement:

**15's complement subtraction**

$=(153)_{16}-(191)_{16}=(153)_{16}+(E6E)_{\text{15s comp}}=FC0$

No end over carry, means result is -ve in 15s complement form. Taking back 15s complement we get 03F. So the solution is $(-03F)_{16}$

However this does not sound correct as $(62)_{10}=(3E)_{16}$ not $(3F)_{16}$.
Where I am doing silly mistake? Or I am completely messed up?

Comment: 153 + E6E = FC1, just sayin'

Comment: yeahh...I found that I have done $(152)_{16}+(E6E)_{\text{15s comp}}$ in my notebook... :\ ...precious time wasted... thanks a ton